# Collatz Conjecture & Grammars / Automata

Tags: fl.formal-languages, nt.number-theory, halting-problem

I was wondering if there is a good bibliography of attempts to investigate the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) as a formal grammar?  (or any other attempts in the CS community to deal with this class of generative phenomena & their "halting" properties).

Comment: as a sort of folklore approach, there is a fairly natural way to study this problem by building an FSM transducer that computes iterates in binary (least significant bit to most significant bit) although have not seen this in a paper. dont know if this construction is in the shallit and wilson paper, that may be the closest published paper to the transducer technique.

Comment: more on collatz conjecture from [FSM transducer angle & misc refs](http://vzn1.wordpress.com/code/collatz-conjecture-experiments/)

Comment: See also this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/123491/collatz-conjecture-finite-state-machine-transducer-construction-origination/138675#138675) and its answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess these papers by Jeffrey C. Lagarias could help:

1. [The 3x+1 problem: An annotated bibliography (1963--1999) (sorted by author)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309224).
2. [The 3x+1 Problem: An Annotated Bibliography, II (2000-2009)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608208).

Another good source is the recent book "[The Ultimate Challenge](http://books.google.com/books?id=hekJ7JDMEVkC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)". In it  chapter "Generalized $3x+1$ functions and the theory of computation",[section $\#$ 8](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=hekJ7JDMEVkC&oi=fnd&pg=PA123#v=onepage&q&f=false), can also be of interest.

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to see what else bubbles up before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Specifically, you may want to check out this paper by Shallit and Wilson: 
[The "3x+1" Problem and Finite Automata", *Bulletin of the EATCS*, 46 (1992), pp. 182-185](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/wilson.pdf).

EDITED TO ADD: This appears as result 8.5 in the "section #8" part of [Oleksandr Bondarenko's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5675/collatz-conjecture-grammars-automata/5676#5676).